How to install an older version of package in msys2?
I would like to install an older version of boost on msys2 to check if newer version of boost causes some issue.
But from https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-boost?repo=ucrt64, I don't see any way to specify the version so it seems that the latest version is always installed.
Any way (or even manually) to install an older version?

I guess you need the old version of boost and build it yourself. You might want to see PKGBUILD file of the current one to see how was compiled in msys2.
